# Why does my shower head stop abruptly after a few minutes?

Tags: plumbing, shower

Recently my shower has been stopping after a couple of minutes. The tub faucet is fine, water pressure everywhere else in the house is fine. I get city water if that matters. I checked my shower head and it's good.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: What happens if you take the shower head off and run the water?

Comment: maybe the hot/cold pressure balance valve locks up after it fills with water due to a small leak

Answer (score 1):

Long shot: perhaps this is one of those energy-saving shower heads that automatically turns off when the water supply has warmed up. You then flip a level on the shower head to restore flow for the duration of the shower. This is for people who turn on the shower to let it warm up while they go do something else; it stops water waste after the water heats up.

Comment: Would you mind posting a link to one of those shower heads? I cannot find one.

Comment: Google `shower head water saver warm up` (without quotes); the first result is one.